# How to align first row of table with a line of text

Tags: html, css

I want to align the first row of a table with a line of text. For example,  I want to achieve

> ** some text ** |first row of table      |
>                          |second row of table|
>                          ...

When I use the `<table>` element it always puts the table on a new line, giving me

> ** some text **
>   |first row of table      |
>   |second row of table|
>   ...

which I do not want.

I only know basic HTML, but not CSS. Still, any solution involving CSS is fine, I just want a quickfix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

or you can also use `rowspan` inside `table`

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2" valign="top">some text</td>
    <td>first row of table</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>second row of table</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice. Integrating the text together with the table. I wish I had thought of that. As I have not learnt CSS, your solution is the one that appeals to me the most.

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the text in a `span` then do, e.g.:

```css
span, table {
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<span>some text</span>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: inline-table` to make table an inline element and align the table with the row.

e.g.

```
table {
    display: inline-table;
}
```